Hybrid search using Azure AI Search and lang chain as a retriever
I am trying to implement a conversational RAG using Azure AiSearch and lang chain with conversational history. I am trying to use the
AzureAISearchRetriever   from   langchain_community.retrievers 

However, the examples in langchain documentation only points us to using default (semantic search) and not much about hybrid search.
https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/integrations/retrievers/azure_ai_search/
Any ideas on how we can implement it using the default AzureAISearchRetriever?

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ai-azure-ai-services-blog/azure-cognitive-search-and-langchain-a-seamless-integration-for/ba-p/3901448  check this

According to this documentation you can do hybrid search using vector store.
Use below code
import os

from langchain_community.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader, TextLoader
from langchain_community.vectorstores import AzureSearch
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAIEmbeddings
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, get_bearer_token_provider, InteractiveBrowserCredential

from langchain_text_splitters import CharacterTextSplitter



vector_store_address="<Ai_search_service_endpoint>"
vector_store_password="<Ai_search_service_key>"

token_provider = get_bearer_token_provider(InteractiveBrowserCredential(), "https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default")

embeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
    model="<embeding-model>",
    azure_endpoint="<Azure_openai_endpoint>",
    azure_ad_token_provider=token_provider
)


index_name = "langchain-vector-demo"

vector_store  = AzureSearch(
    azure_search_endpoint=vector_store_address,
    azure_search_key=vector_store_password,
    index_name=index_name,
    embedding_function=embeddings.embed_query,
)


loader = TextLoader(r"<Text documnet paths>", encoding="utf-8")

documents = loader.load()
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=400, chunk_overlap=0)
docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

vector_store.add_documents(documents=docs)



docs = vector_store.similarity_search(
    query="Wine quality",
    k=3,
    search_type="hybrid",
)

for i in docs:
    print(i.page_content)

or
docs = vector_store.hybrid_search(
    query="What did the president say about Ketanji Brown Jackson", k=3
)

Above is using vector store but you can convert that to as retriver with search type as hybrid.
dv = vector_store.as_retriever(search_type="hybrid")
dv.invoke("<your query>")


This seems to be the correct answer. However, that leaves me with the question of the actual purpose of AzureAISearchRetriever.
